# How to insert "tab" character in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

In Qt Creator (3.0.1, Ubuntu 14.04.LTS), how do you insert a literal "tab" character (`\t`) (into a C source file) in the Text Editor?  (Within a line, the **Tab** key inserts spaces as per your C++ Indentation level setting.)

At the moment I am having to find a tab character somewhere and use copy & paste.  I expected to find some sort of "InsertLiteralCharacter" Command in **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard**, but there isn't one.  (While we are there, I see that Commands **Indent** & **Unindent** claim to be unbound, but **Tab** & **Shift+Tab** respectively do these; don't know why those are not shown?)

[EDIT: For clarity, I want to insert a tab character *into* (the middle of) lines.  I am *not* asking about tab character behaviour for indenting at the start of a line.]

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a Make file which requires tab's
and your indention is based on insert spaces, you
can insert a tab character using:
Ctrl+Alt+I

Answer (score 1):

In case this ancient issue still exists or others are facing it: I encountered the same problem with QtCreator 7.0.2 and could solve it by disabling the ClangFormat-Plugin (which I accidentally enabled).

Help -> About Plugins -> Search: *Format* -> uncheck the plugin

[Dialog to disable ClangFormat Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD5P8.png)

Answer (score 0):

How the tab key is handled in C++ code is configured in the settings for C++ (Tools>Options>C++). I can not check the exact place right now, but there is box with different options on how to handle tabs in there.

You can have tab indent the line whenever it is pressed or do not use it to indent at all or have it indent only when hit in the leading whitespace of a line.

Comment: I am aware of this.  However the point of my question is that I want to insert a tab **INTO** (the middle of) a line **NOT** for indent at the start of the line.

Comment: It can use tab like normal if you do not ask the editor to indent the current line whenever you hit tab:-)

Answer (score 0):

I have been pulling out what little hair I have over tabs being changed to spaces using QtCreator 11.0.2 and disabling the plugin did not help.

I found that going into Edit->Preferences and choosing C++, on the Code Style tab, in the General sub-tab where the details about Tabs and Indentation was showing the Tab Policy as "Spaces Only" with the "Qt [built in]" code style selected.

Going over to Projects and selecting Code Style, I found there was no Edit function (not that I expected to be able to edit a built-in, but a greyed-out button didn't even exist) and there was no Create button.

However, there were Import and Export buttons. I used the Export button to export the Code Style as an XML file, and made changes to the following lines:

Value was "true":

```
<value type="bool" key="SpacesForTabs">false</value>
```

Value was "Qt":

```
<value type="QString">Qt Personal</value>
```

After saving, I imported this and had a new Code Style called "Qt Personal", which I was able to select globally and the problem was fixed.